# Way to reverse strings to RTL without numbers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying in unity by using TMP_input, to when player write something in (in Hebrew) so the output will be RTL, I am using the option to check the RTL and its working , the problem is the numbers are reversed as well, which I'm trying to avoid.
Is there a way to make the chars/strings go RTL, but in the same input when use numbers it will stay the same as LTR?

I did try to make some scripts to use Split the string and numbers, but it always change the whole Input to LTR/RTL

Comment: RTL layout and display is not usually done by reversing strings, but is handled in the UI layer by setting the appropriate attributes for the text display calls, and the framework handles the hard work of parsing text into a font's glyphs, shaping, and laying them out. Unfortunately, a little web searching shows that Unity may not have support for Bidi languages (at least as of 2020). I did find this which might help: https://nosuchstudio.medium.com/making-a-right-to-left-layout-for-unitys-ui-a3a4979fba28

Comment: See also https://forum.unity.com/threads/support-rtl-languages-in-unity-engine.956814/

Comment: There's also this project: [RTL Text Mesh Pro (github)](https://github.com/pnarimani/RTLTMPro)

Answer (score 0):

You can try reversing the sencence and then reverse *each number* back with a help of *regular expressions*, e.g.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string text = "This is a number 123.4 not a word";

...

// drow a ton 123.4 rebmun a si sihT
var result = Regex.Replace(
   string.Concat(text.Reverse()), 
 @"[0-9]*\.[0-9]+-?", 
   match => string.Concat(match.Value.Reverse()));
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A9SxBk)